# move constructor - is `new A()` rvalue?

Tags: c++

```
struct Ex
{
    Ex()
    {
        std::cout<<"Default"<<std::endl;
    }

    Ex(const Ex &obj)
    {
        std::cout<<"Copy"<<std::endl;
    }

    Ex(Ex &&obj)
    {
        std::cout<<"Move"<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
   std::vector<Ex*> myVector;
   myVector.push_back( new Ex() );
}
```

Output:
`Default`

Is `new Ex()` not a rvalue? Why is only default constructor getting called?

Comment: You are pushing a pointer, not the object it points to, into the vector

Comment: Someone should finally write an article "Why C++ objects are not new()?", and it should be mandatory to read for anyone posting a first question tagged C++.

Comment: @bipll I am oficially stealing the title of `"*You don't really need `new` objects in C++*". Gonna write the article in the near future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
myVector.push_back( new Ex() );
```

You call the default constructor `Ex::Ex()` with `new Ex()`, which creates a new object on the heap. Then you only push the pointer to this new object to vector, not the object itselt. That means only the pointer is copied, not the object it's pointing to. Thus, there is no need to call any copy-constructor.

You can get the desired behaviour when using actual object instead of just pointers:

```
int main()
{
// no pointer VVVV
   std::vector<Ex> myVector;
   myVector.push_back( Ex{} );
}
```